# Mutiple buttons with the same name showing different divs

Tags: javascript, html, css, onclick

I have a large amount of buttons all used to display a div before it, my question is instead of having 20 different javascript functions which all do the same thing, is it possible to do with one? By default i have the display set to none in the CSS.

HTML:

```
<div class="col-lg-6 event-title">
    <span>Special Olympics Unified Snowboarding Final</span>
    <dd>SLOPESTYLE</dd>

    <div id ="#dropdown">
        <h6>2016 RESULTS</h6>
        <p>
         GOLD - Chris Klug & Henry Meece<br>
         SILVER - Danny Davis & Zach Elder<br>
         BRONZE - Hannah teter & Daina Shilts
         </p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-lg-1">
    <button type="button" id = "#drop-button" class="btn btn-default btn-lrg">&#x25BC</button>
</div>

<div class="col-lg-6 event-title">
    <span>Special Olympics Unified Snowboarding Final</span>
    <dd>SLOPESTYLE</dd>

    <div id ="#dropdown1">
        <h6>2016 RESULTS</h6>
        <p>
         GOLD - Chris Klug & Henry Meece<br>
         SILVER - Danny Davis & Zach Elder<br>
         BRONZE - Hannah teter & Daina Shilts
         </p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-lg-1">
    <button type="button" id = "#drop-button1" class="btn btn-default btn-lrg">&#x25BC</button>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById("#drop-button").addEventListener("click", function(){
    document.getElementById("#dropdown").style.display="block";
});

document.getElementById("#drop-button1").addEventListener("click", function(){
    document.getElementById("#dropdown1").style.display="block";
});
```

Comment: You can use query selector all to group all your buttons into one clickable event http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_queryselectorall.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an outer div

```
<div id='container'> 
 your other divs
</div>
```

then assign a query selector to the div container and specify what events you want to track like click , change etc.

```
var g = {};

g.formClass = function()
{
   /*call this method with <body onload = g.c.assignEventListeners();>*/
 this.assignEventListners = function()
 {
  /*event listener for all links in the container div*/
container = document.querySelector("#container");
container.addEventListener("click", g.c.containerRouter, false);
container.addEventListener("change", g.c.containerRouter, false);
};
```

send the events to a router, to detect what was touched in the div container and execute your specific code

Here are some examples of how you can monitor the events and make decision on what you want to do.

```
this.containerRouter = function (e) 
{
  if (e.target !== e.currentTarget) 
  {
    /*Reference the event's target id*/
    if (e.target.id.indexOf('drop-button')>-1)
      g.c.changeDisplay(e);

    /*Reference the event's target class along with the type of event*/
    if (e.target.classList[0]=='selMe' && e.type=='click')
      document.getElementById(e.target.id).select();
    if (e.target.classList[1]=='subMe' && e.type=='change')
      g.c.subTotHrs(e);
  }
  e.stopPropagation();
};

this.changeDisplay = function(e)
{
  /* 
  * Get a list of all <div> elements in the document with class="dropdown" 
  * store them in a array variable x
  */
  var x = document.querySelectorAll("div.dropdown"); 

  /*loop through the array and close all drop downs*/
  for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++ )
    x[i].style.display="none"; 

  /*
  * use the .split( ) method to extract the button #
  * this puts the parts into an array you can reference
  */
  var divNum = e.target.id.split('drop-button');
  document.getElementById('#dropdown'+divNum[1]).style.display="block";

};

}
g.c = new g.formClass;
```

You can access anything from the event's target like id, class, value etc.  You can evaluate what type of event occurred.  There simply are a whole lot more options available to you.

You can assign the query selector to the whole document or narrow down the scope to a `<tbody>` node so for example, if you are dynamically populating a table with buttons or text fields they can all be checked with this one event listener

pass along the event ....(e) and your functions/methods/sub-routines can use it to get or place useful information.

In this example I wrapped all the code in a global object.  You can choose to do the same or not, just change the references to the functions/methods you wish to execute.  I included more than you needed just to show some of the possibilities.

Here is the code needed for your specific question

HTML

```
<div id ='container'>
  <div class="col-lg-6 event-title">
    <span>Special Olympics Unified Snowboarding Final</span>
    <dd>SLOPESTYLE</dd>

    <div id ="#dropdown1">
      <h6>2016 RESULTS</h6>
      <p>
        GOLD - Chris Klug & Henry Meece<br>
        SILVER - Danny Davis & Zach Elder<br>
        BRONZE - Hannah teter & Daina Shilts
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-1">
    <button type="button" id = "#drop-button1" class="btn btn-default btn-lrg">&#x25BC</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

javaScript

```
function assignEventListners(){
  container = document.querySelector("#container");
  container.addEventListener("click", containerRouter, false);
}

function containerRouter(e) {
  if (e.target !== e.currentTarget)
    if (e.target.id.indexOf('drop-button')>-1)
      changeDisplay(e);

    e.stopPropagation();
}

function changeDisplay(e)
{
  var x = document.querySelectorAll("div.dropdown"); 
  for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++ )
    x[i].style.display="none";

  var divNum = e.target.id.split('drop-button');
  document.getElementById('#dropdown'+divNum[1]).style.display="block";
};
```

Please note the change in the code.  To explain the purpose of the "containerRouter", I have moved the previous code out of that method and created a new method called "changeDisplay"

How it all works:

1. the eventListner is added to the outer div "Container", so anytime the user does something inside the container an event is fired.
2. The eventListner sends all request for events you have specified like click, change, mouseover etc. to one method "containerRouter".  The neat part when it does this containerRouter receives one parameter "e".
   "e" is the event.  And it comes with a lot of stuff you can use.
3. The "containerRouter" should only contain code that directs the fired event to the appropriate method/function.  Otherwise you may as well have a bunch of separate event listeners as you stated in your original post.
4. In the "containerRouter" you can evaluate "e". What kind of event.  Where specifically did it come from. Was there content associated with the object that generated the event.  Here's a couple of examples.  You could use the "change" event when you leave a text field.  You could examine and validate the content.  Or if someone mouses over an area of the page you could read the innerHTML of the object and display it change it whatever.

Specifically what we did with your example we looked for a sub string "drop-down" in the event's target id.  The target is the object that generated the event like your buttons.  You gave each button a unique id. But also there was a part of the ids that were all the same, so we took advantage of that.  Using the substring search method of .indexOf('drop-button') > -1, we said if that condition was true it must be a button. You can google indexOf. So go do something.  In this case change the display of the screen.

Notice that when we called the method/function changeDisplay we sent along "e", because it still has stuff we can use.

In the changeDisplay method the first thing we do is use the method .querySelecorAll().  It gives us an array of all the objects on our page that match the search criteria which is `<div>` that have a class called "dropdown".  This saves us the need to loop through the objects on the page to gather up the information.  So now we have a quick reference to all those objects. A simple loop goes through and closes them all even if they are already closed.

Next we have to figure out which of your buttons was pushed.  This is where "e" comes in handy. We just extract the id value of e.target.id and then dissect it to find the number.  We attach the number to the `<div id="dropdown">` we want to popup and voila it's done as I have explained above.

Comment: Wow! Thank's for putting so much effort into a detailed answer really appreciate it. I have it working currently however I was just wondering if you could further explain the containerRouter function, just to make sure I know whats actually going on. Also if I wanted it so that you could only have one dropdown open at a time would I just add a bool variable which gets toggled on click, then add a check which checks if it is true, then close whatever dropdown is open and open the one that was just clicked? Cheers man, you're a legend!

Comment: Your 2nd question only one drop down shown at a time. You just need to cycle through all your drop down <div>s and close them.  I will expand my answer to show you how.  I will be using the .querySelectorAll() method

Comment: What is the IF statement (e.target != e.currenTarget) used for? I've found out that e.target provides a reference to the object that dispatched the event and e.currentTarget identifies the current target for the event. But don't understand the need to make sure that these are not equal to each other? @Claus

Comment: The IF statement simply checks to make sure you clicked something inside the object you assigned the event listener to and not the object itself. Not a good explanation so maybe this [link to another post](http://blog.bittersweetryan.com/2013/04/a-quick-look-at-etarget-and.html) can explain it better.  The event bubbles up the document tree.  Also note we stop the bubbling after one try with e.stopPropagation();

Answer (score 2):

Why are you using id's?
Id's are unique and for multiple you should use classes instead.

Answer (score 1):

HTML:

```
<div class="col-lg-1">
    <button type="button" class="drop-button btn btn-default btn-lrg">&#x25BC</button>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("drop-button");
for(var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    buttons[i].addEventListener("click", function(){ this.style.display="block"; });
{
```

Comment: I've implemented this however the part I need to display is in a separate div "dropdown", how would i go about adding this in instead?

Comment: see my example on how to use the .split() method to extract the number from the button clicked and attach it to the <div> id.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a function like this:

```
function yourfunction(id1, id2) {
    document.getElementById(id1).addEventListener("click", function(){
        document.getElementById(id2).style.display="block";
    });
}
```

And call it in your script:

```
yourfunction("#drop-button", "#dropdown");
yourfunction("#drop-button1", "#dropdown1");
// more ids
```