# WooCommerce - Adding two items to cart with 0.1s latency, first not added

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

**CONTEXT**

I have a WooCommerce site where users fairly quickly select up to 50 items. They then click on the checkout button and proceed to the cart and checkout pages.

**PROBLEM**

If a user selects items very quickly (e.g. Click Item 1 -> 0.1s -> Click Item 2), then Item 1 will not appear in the cart. This is probably because the Ajax call for Item 1 is interrupted when you very quickly select Item 2.

**QUESTION**

Is there a way to modify the functionality of WooCommerce so that a low latency between selections does not interfere with adding to cart?

Comment: Store selected items in an array. Use an event listener to monitor which items are clicked. Send the selections  in the array as a group instead of separate transactions.  If you have variable number of items displayed in a dynamically populated table or div use .querySelector to set one event listener for all nodes to be checked. See my example of how to set that up at this stack overflow  [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40618259/mutiple-buttons-with-the-same-name-showing-different-divs/40618656#40618656)

Comment: You can also disable all other add_to_cart buttons during the cart update  ?

Comment: @Claus - thank you, this was helpful!